# count and display each duplicate value in a column using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

i want to count and display each duplicate value in a column from the below table using php mysql

```
name  
AAA
BBB
BBB
BBB
AAA
CCC
```

result should be like below

```
AAA-2
BBB-3
CCC-1
```

Comment: can i give you sql query.?

Comment: you need sql query.?

Comment: Ccc is not duplicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select name, count(name) as count from table_name group by name
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by providing an explanation rather than just a bit of code.

Answer (score 3):

You need :

```
select name,count(1) from yourtable group by name
```

If you need output with hyphen (-)

```
select concat(name,'-',count(1)) from yourtable group by name
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
select name, count(*) from <table> group by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) c_name FROM tablename GROUP BY name HAVING c_name>1
```

Comment: Because of the HAVING clause, this does not provide the correct result.

Answer (score -1):

`<?php
    require_once('connection.php');
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,
                        "SELECT colum_name, concat(count(1),'-',colum_name)
                         as colum_name
                         FROM table_name
                         group by colum_name
                         order by colum_name desc");
    while (  $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo $data['colum_name']."<br>";
    }`

Comment: Am assumig you want to display data using php from the database. That will give you result: AAA-2 BBB-3 CCC-1 ( with your column name  and table name respectively).